# Spliting the href to get a variable and send it to php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3  tags and href for each tag. I want to send the "page" variable to php file to process, but when I use the code, then the php file can get the value of $_GET['page']. I use "print_r($_GET), it showed me the data sent like Array([index.php?page]=>1), from that I can know that the variable that sent to server is not 'page'

```html
var data = $(this).attr("href");
```

I tried to split the href string, using

```html
var data = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
```

the result of print_r($_GET) is Array([undefined] =>). Until now, i don't know how to solve this problem! :(

Here is my index.php:

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="index.php?page=1" class="page">Test page 1</a>
  <a href="index.php?page=2" class="page">Test page 2</a>
  <a href="index.php?page=3" class="page">Test page 3</a>
  <div id="content_result" style="margin-left:5px; width: 990px; min-height: 600px; border:1px solid #000;">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //svar anchortag = $("a.page");   
      $("a.page").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'page.php',
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#content_result').html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my page.php:

```html
<?php
    //$tam = $_GET['page'];
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    else{
        $page = ''; 
    }
        if($page == '1'){
            echo 'This is page  1!';    
        }elseif($page == '2'){
            echo 'This is page  2!';        
        }elseif($page == '3'){
            echo 'This is page  3!';
        }else{
            echo 'Pls choose page!';    
        }
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href').split('?')[0];`

Comment: @tan it depends on which part of the array the user needs if first then 0 if second then 1

Comment: i will try and tell you the result :)

Comment: Alright, the value [1] is the best choose for me. Thanks so much @guradio

Comment: glad to help mate happy coding.. btw if you have other `?` in your link it will not work so you have to be carefull

Comment: Can you reduce the example to either the client or the server side?

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = window.location.search.replace('?', '');
href.split('&');
```

Here `window.location.search` will only return the query string part of the url, on which using replace will make '?' disappear. Than you can get all the of the parameters in array by splitting url with respect to '&'.